# Connecting to Wifi: org.freedesktop.resolve1: Permission denied

Tags: linux, wifi, freedesktop, dhcpcd

I have this problem when I try to connect to the wifi.

If I run `resolvectl` I get the following error:

```bash
resolvectl
Failed to get global data: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.resolve1: Permission denied
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: How are you attempting to connect to the wifi? Are you going thru the NetworkManager gui, ...or?

Comment: @amphetamachine I don't think that will influence the resolution of the problem, but I am using PuppyLinux's Simple Network Manager. But even simpler, if I run resolvectl I get that error.

Comment: when would you ever run resolvectl manually in a situation where you need to connect to a wifi? Bit confused. I don't know Puppy Linux, so is the "Simple Network Manager" like a GUI tool that uses NetworkManager, or something else?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The Simple Network Manager does not use NetworkManager by default, it is possible that it uses it, but it is not normal, now I am using `dhcpcd` and for some reason that error appears, perhaps we should look at the SystemD source code. The problem comes from `resolvectl`.